# How can I handle the "Django - Database error: no such table" error?

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to django and I'm stuck at the problem with models. Here is my users app's models file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator
from django.urls import reverse
from PIL import Image




class Schedule(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    context = models.TextField()


class Input(models.Model):
    DAYS_OF_FITNESS = [
       ('month', '30'),
       ('month_2', '60'),
       ('month_3', '90'),
   ]
    weight = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(40)])
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(12)])
    days = models.CharField(
    max_length=20, choices=DAYS_OF_FITNESS, default='30')
    athlete = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to link each user with its input using OneToOneField and Schedule is linked as a foreign key to Input model

But when I'm trying to migrate models, I'm getting this error:

```
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: users_input
```

I checked that Both models are in django settings, and I migrated them. BTW, I'm using signals to save inputs automatically, (just for note if it helps)

Comment: Did you migrate your database changes

Comment: I migrated every change

Answer (score 0):

It's because that table doesn't exist in the database. To create tables you have to do the following. Execute the following commands in your terminal.

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

Comment: When I run python manage.py makemigrations, I'm getting no changes detected, But when I run python mange.py migrate, I'm getting no such table: users_input error